# Significant variable with no effect in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, interpretation

In my logistic regression model, I have one independent variable that has a B value of 0, p = 0.006 and exp(B) = 1. Goodness-of-fit measures indicate that the model is acceptably "good".

Intuitively, I would imagine a significant variable to have a non-zero coefficient and some effect. Statistically though, I am not sure.

So, I am not sure if the outcome on this variable is an acceptable outcome. If yes, what is the explanation? If this type of outcome [B=0, p=0.006, exp(B)=1] is not acceptable, what could it be symptomatic of -- what is the problem?

Comment: p-value for what? Which null hypothesis?

Answer (score 12):

Are you sure the B has not been rounded too much?  If the predictor is measured in, say, $, you may need 5 or 6 decimal places on B and its odds ratio in order to see the effect.

Comment: Yep, it seems a problem with the scale of the variable. Try to use antoher scale (divide by 1000, use log etc.)

Comment: Hahaha, unbelievable! you are right - about the decimal places. Thanks!